# Matlab table GroupBy values and count

Tags: matlab

I have a table .csv imported into MATLAB. Now I want to find some statistics about the data.

| Date Of Month | No. of Items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 7 |

Now I want to group the first column in a way that 2nd column sums based on the first column. Example of expected output

| Date Of Month | No. of Items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 10 |

I have gone through the Matlab documentation on groupsummary, groupcounts etc. but could not get the desired result. Appreciate anyones help/hint on how to achieve this.

Comment: If your data is as simple as this, I'd suggest converting it to an array and using `accumarray`.

Comment: You can also use `splitapply`, which is siimilar to `accumarray`

Comment: Got it. Thanks.